# Pairing two sets without common pairs

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be 10 men and 10 women. Suppose that no two man can have sex with *two* same woman, and vice versa. How many intimate relationship can happen?

For example for 3 man and woman there can be 6 relationship, and for 5 pairs it seems to be 12.

I am sure that this question has been asked before in different setup. For example I suppose that asymptotically this is same as asking how many covering relations a finite lattice can have -- I think that maximum happens when the lattice is graded of rank three and "men" and "women" corresponds to two middle levels.

Comment: I do not follow your logic for 3men and women you get a total of three.  If you are looking at the number of possible individual pairs, surely you get $9$.  If you are looking at the number of perfect matchings where everyone must be in a relationship and we look at the overall outcome, then surely there are six possible...

Comment: I mean that if a man A had sex with women 1 and 2, then man B can have sex with women 1 or with women 2, but not with both. I would use better terminology if I knew one.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "no two man can have sex with *two* same woman" or what you mean by "how many intimate relationship". If you have 3 men (A, C, E) and 3 women (B, D, F) then why can't you have 6 "intimate relationships": A&B, B&C, C&D, D&E, E&F, F&A?

Comment: So... you are asking, in terms of graph theory, what is the maximum number of edges in a bipartite graph with $10$ vertices in each part such that for any pair of vertices $\{u,v\}$ you have $N(u)\cap N(v)=\emptyset$?  I would imagine the maximum occurs when you have one promiscuous man and one promiscuous woman, who each are in a relationship with everyone from the opposite sex simultaneously, giving an answer for $n$ men and $n$ women as being $2n-1$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer if you stated the problem ***mathematically***? It sounds as if you are asking for the maximum size (number of edges) of a spanning subgraph of $K_{n,n}$ which contains no $K_{2,2}$ but this doesn't agree with your example for $n=3$.

Comment: @JMoravitz It sounds to me more like he wants $|N(u)\cap N(v)|\le1.$

Comment: @benguin But $|f|\le|M|$ so how does he get an answer of $12$ when $n=6$?

Comment: Arghs, I had wrong numbers in the question. Corrected.

Comment: With the interpretation by bof and correcting my earlier mistake, this becomes the [Zarankiewicz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarankiewicz_problem).  It doesn't appear that a closed formula is known explicitly, but we know that for $n$ men and $n$ women, it will be on the order of $n^{3/2}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thanks! That was the right term to search for. Could you make this an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Are you asking how many pairs may happen with the condition that for any $(w_i,m_i)$ and $(w_j,m_j) \in C$ the pairs set,  $(w_i,m_j)$ and $(w_j,m_i)$ should be excluded ? In this case, the answer might be obvious. Or else what do you want to count exactly ?

Comment: Another advantage of actually stating this problem mathematically is that it avoids discriminatory assumptions—in this case, that all people are heterosexual.

Comment: @greg-martin, don't worry: I am a supported of equal marriage rights. (But I really understand problems faster, if they have real life example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rephrasing of the [Zarankiewicz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarankiewicz_problem) specifically asking to calculate the number $z(10,2)$.

> The number $z(n,t)$ represents the largest number of edges in a subgraph, $H$, of the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ such that $H$ has no $K_{t,t}$ subgraph.

[This paper](http://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=9778&context=theses) includes a table of several small values of $n$ in appendix C in table $C.0$  (*in the linked table, he uses the notation $z(m,n;t)$ where it is defined similarly as above but the parent graph is instead the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$.  The diagonal contains the entries we are curious of*)

In particular, it reads that $z(10,2) = 34$

There is no convenient closed form solution for $z(n,2)$ for general $n$, however there is a known result by Kovari, Zos, and Turan that it is on the order of $n^{3/2}$ (*citation can be found on the wiki page*).